# How to display a button based on object id and div id

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to display a button on a div, which will only show if the id of the div is within the JSON object. I've figured out a solution, but I think it's very poor as it is hardcoded. I'm fairly new to angular so if anyone could propose an alternate solution (to this and the coloring of the element itself on click as it has the same hardcoded issue) I would really appreciate it

The provided stackblitz is a simplified version of the problem

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay8xem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you looking for this:
(the rest looks fine for me, maybe someone will offer a better way...)

```
  <div #yourDiv id="1" style="height: 100px;" [ngClass]="{'colored': color === 1}">
    <button id="abc" (click)="color = 1">WE WANT MORE BUTTONS HERE</button>
    <button *ngIf="hasReminder(yourDiv.id)">HiddenButton</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I guess that's just how angular works then? No way to avoid it :(, thank you for the answer though!

Comment: If u are not happy with this then I misunderstood your question, as this is the simplet way to display a buton debending on the divs id.

Answer (score 0):

You can get at least a bit easier if you store the `id`'s in an array and iterate that array:

```
ids = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let id of ids">
  <div [id]="id" style="height: 100px;" [ngClass]="{'colored': color === id}">
    <button id="abc" (click)="color = id">WE WANT MORE BUTTONS HERE</button>
    <button *ngIf="hasReminder(id)">HiddenButton</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqie8l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

But this could be a correct place for directive, so look into that: [Official Docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)